# Flickering when rendering with lwjgl on windows 8.1

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

When i render a mesh with lwjgl on my windows 8 computer i get weird flickering.

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Jae2Zf7IkQ)

With exactly the same code (except for lwjgl natives) the image renders properly on my old MacBook.

So why does this just happen in windows 8.

fragment shader

```
#version 400core 


in vec2 texCords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLight;
in vec3 toCamera;
in vec3 position_out;
in float distanceToCamera_out;

uniform vec3 diffuseLightColor;
uniform vec3 specularLightColor;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void){

vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
vec3 unitToLight = normalize(toLight);

//temporary
vec4 color = vec4(1,1,1,1);

//diffuse light
float diffuseFactor = max(dot(unitNormal, unitToLight),0);
vec3 diffuse = diffuseLightColor * diffuseFactor;

//specular light
vec3 reflected = reflect(-unitToLight,unitNormal);
float specularFactor = max(dot(reflected,normalize(toCamera)),0);
specularFactor = pow(specularFactor,50); //dampening
vec3 specular = specularLightColor * specularFactor;


//final light
vec3 finalLight = diffuse + specular;

//final color
out_Color = color * vec4(finalLight,1);
}
```

render function

```
public void render(Entity entity) {
    TexturedModel texModel=entity.getModel();
    RawModel model=texModel.getModel();
    ModelTexture texture = texModel.getTexture();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getBaseId());

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoId());

    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.getVboiId());
              shader.loadTransformation(Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRx(), entity.getRy(), entity.getRz(), entity.getScale()));
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

GPU: gtx 970

Answer (score 0):

In your video I see no flickering.  However you may be experiencing screen tear...?  If this is the case, add `Display.setVSyncEnabled(true)`.  You could also have fragmentation, and that is hardware issue and nothing wrong with your coding.